# Angular Data Table expanded row taking space of only 1 column of parent

Tags: angular, html-table, angular-material

Ive made an Angular Expandable Data Table but the expanded raw always take space of only 1 column of its parent. This is more or less my CSS code:

```
    .mat-table {
    display:table;
    width:100%;

    > .mat-header-row, > .mat-row {
        display: table-row;

        > .mat-header-cell, > .mat-cell {
            display: table-cell;
            font-size: 12px;

            vertical-align: middle;
            border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
        }
    }
}
```

The expanded row contains another table so it might be the problem but i dont know how to fix that.
This is how it looks like right now:

(Expanded row has a gray color and contains another table with 1 element)
[image]
After expanding:
[image]

I am not using the approach for Expandable rows from Angular Material docs, I am using my own cdk and expanded row is being stored in:

```
<ng-template #tpl let-element></ng-template>
```

Everything looks fine when I am using `display: flex`, but I cant use it in this scenario. So I think I have to change my CSS and thats where the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible, see [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/am-all-imports-svee9v?file=app%2Fapp.component.html) stackblitz.

I don't think your problem lies in your CSS, more likely you are not setting the `colspan` of your table container to more than one column. Can you show the template code of your expanded detail row where the nested table is located?

From the Angular Material [documentation](https://material.angular.io/components/table/examples), check the code of the table with expandable rows.

```html
<ng-container matColumnDef="expandedDetail">
  <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" [attr.colspan]="columnsToDisplay.length">
    <!-- your table here -->
  </td>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: Can you post some more of the template code from the mat-table and the expanded row? Even better, make a small stackblitz with only the necessities / static data. Bit hard to understand what's going on without the whole code.